# How to use Struts 2 with Velocity and Tiles

Tags: java, struts2, velocity, tiles

Has anyone been able to get velocity and tiles working with struts 2?

I am having some problem finding examples or tutorials online and from what I have gathered from mailing lists it seems it might not even be possible at all (but the mails were quite old).

Answer (score 0):

https://struts.apache.org/docs/tiles-plugin.html

You can start with the documentation from apache struts. I am using tiles and velocity both and they are working fine. I am using velocity for the emailing templates and tiles for the front-end templates.

You can also refer to various examples on Dzone, TutorialsPoint as well as Mykong. They have provided good examples.