# Struts2 tags are not working in Velocity templates

Tags: java, struts2, velocity, tiles2

I am using struts2 with Apache Tiles2 and Velocity templates in my webapp.
The problem I am getting is that struts2 tags are not evaluating in velocity templates only when I use velocity with tiles.

But when I use only velocity with struts2 it handles the struts2 tags.

Can any one help ?

**Details:**
I have integrated tiles with velocity using this [article](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/integration/velocity.html).
Then, I want to use struts2 with tiles so I configured struts tiles by following [this](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/tiles-plugin.html)

**Result :**
I have successfully run my application on browser after above integrations. 
Tiles, velocity and struts2 tiles plugin are working correctly.

**Problem :** 
Struts2 tags, like #stext("My Text")) etc.., are not evaluating/working in velocity.
Velocity is display them as text like "#stext("My Text"))". 
The above expression should evaluate and display My Text instead of #stext("My Text")).

**Note** : Velocity specific tags are working perfectly in above scenario.

Comment: Same question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019692/struts2-with-velocity-and-tiles and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320049/struts-2-tiles-velocity-interoperability , quite interesting because none has (real) answers. Could you provide an `SSCCE` (http://sscce.org/) or at least more details about your configuration ?

Comment: Strange I've done some simple testing with velocity, jsp's and freemarker including mixing all of them to create a single view just to prove that it does indeed work. To resolve the issue show your pom and or list current dependencies and versions. Also how are you integrating tiles? With the tiles plugin?

Comment: @Quaternion : Yes you are right. When i use simply velocity with struts action the struts2 tags are working perfectly. Same is not happening when i use sampe velocity file with tiles.

Comment: Oh I see... You followed that article... Simply use the latest tiles plugin (for tiles version 3) this has some pretty heavy dependance requirements but it will also cover freemarker. In other words you shouldn't need to do anything extra other than add the latest plugin: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Tiles+3+Plugin also see this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337938/how-to-integrate-struts-2-with-tiles-3 (which also mentions the plugin and how to implement it from scratch).